# Media player at your service

Tags: java, javafx

I have a very basic version of a media player built using JavaFX. The project is well segregated and has a different packages for controllers, utils and supporter classes.

My project follows the MVC pattern and it contains the following important parts:

- All the views are in FXML files.
- These views have dedicated controllers for them, all inside the `com.ita.controller` package.
- Some custom controls / dialogs inside the `com.ita.ui` package.
- Utility classes inside the `com.ita.util`.
- The `Main` class extends [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) and is the entry point. It is also responsible for invocation and loading the views into the stage.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/ita/fxml/mediaplayer.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 650, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        MediaPlayerController controller = ((MediaPlayerController) loader.getController());
        // Load Playlist FXML and inject controller/root
        FXMLLoader playListLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/ita/fxml/playlist.fxml"));
        playListLoader.load();
        controller.injectPlayListController((PlaylistController) playListLoader.getController());
        controller.injectPlayListRoot(playListLoader.getRoot());
        bindSize(controller, scene);
        controller.setStage(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        controller.applyDragAndDropFeatures(scene);
    }

    private void bindSize(MediaPlayerController controller, Scene scene){
        controller.timerSliderWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(500));
        controller.mediaViewWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        controller.mediaViewHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(70));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**PlaylistController.java**

```
public class PlaylistController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button add;

    @FXML
    private Button delete;

    @FXML
    private ListView playList;

    private ObservableList playListFiles =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObjectProperty<Path> selectedMedia = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private ObjectProperty<Path> deletedMedia = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        playList.setOnMouseClicked((click) -> {
            if (click.getClickCount() == 2) {
                if (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    selectedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void add(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Files",
                        PropertiesUtils.readFormats()));
        List<Path> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<Path>();
        listOfFiles = FileUtils.convertListFiletoListPath(chooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()));
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            listOfFiles.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
            listOfFiles.stream().forEach(playListFiles::add);
            playListFiles.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
            playList.setItems(playListFiles);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void delete(ActionEvent event) {
        if (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
            if(null!=playListFiles || !playListFiles.isEmpty()) {
                deletedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                playListFiles.remove(playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                playList.setItems(playListFiles);
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableList listViewItems(){
       return playListFiles;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Path> selectedFile(){
        return selectedMedia;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Path> deletedFile() {
        return deletedMedia;
    }
}
```

**PropertiesUtils.java**

```
public class PropertiesUtils {
    public static Map<String, String> readDetails()
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try{
            InputStream in = PropertiesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("details.properties");
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(in);
            map.put("name", p.getProperty("name"));
            map.put("version", p.getProperty("version"));
            map.put("link", p.getProperty("link"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List<String> readFormats()
    {
        List<String> formats = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream in = PropertiesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("details.properties");
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(in);
            formats = Arrays.asList(p.getProperty("formats").split(","));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formats;
    }
}
```

I wanted to add more functionality into the project, but before doing that I just wanted to know if my code follows:

- Code standards that an open source project should. *I am aware of the fact that proper documentation is missing, and I am working on the same.*
- Naming conventions.
- Coupling. I have got some reviews that my code is very tightly coupled. If you have the same view, please write some suggestions on how to overcome it.
- Am I writing the utility classes as they should be written? Mostly, the method definitions and declaring them static.

[GitHub](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/MediaPlayerFX)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on who you ask,  this piece of code could be changed slightly to reduce nesting

> ```
> @FXML
> void delete(ActionEvent event) {
>     if (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
>         if(null!=playListFiles || !playListFiles.isEmpty()) {
>             deletedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
>             playListFiles.remove(playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
>             playList.setItems(playListFiles);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

there really isn't a reason for putting in another if statement, just merge the condition statements into one condition

```
@FXML
void delete(ActionEvent event) {
    if ((playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) &&
            (null!=playListFiles || !playListFiles.isEmpty()) {
        deletedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        playListFiles.remove(playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        playList.setItems(playListFiles);
    }
}
```

Same here

> ```
> @Override
> public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
>     playList.setOnMouseClicked((click) -> {
>         if (click.getClickCount() == 2) {
>             if (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
>                 selectedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
>             }
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

I just put the conditionals together, does the exact same thing as your code, but slightly clearer

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    playList.setOnMouseClicked((click) -> {
        if ((click.getClickCount() == 2) && (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null)) {
                selectedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That was a nice catch.

Comment: I'd even prefer to go for an early return in Guard-Clause style I think

Comment: these wouldn't be a good spot for that, there isn't a whole lot going on in these methods for a Guard clause to be worth while.  the Mouse Click specifically should stay this way, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

This is on top of the other good points already mentioned.

#### Catch the most specific `Exception` type

Catching `Exception` is dangerous,
because it can mask something truly unexpected.
For example if you're really expecting an `IOException`,
but an `EmptyStackException` happens (truly unexpected),
it will be caught by `catch (Exception e)` and you may never even notice.

Secondly,
catching the most specific exception helps readers of the code,
by telling what exactly can go wrong with that piece of code.

#### Limit the scope of `try` blocks

It's good to limit the scope of `try` blocks to the smallest possible,
to prevent exceptions thrown from unexpected places.

#### Avoid code duplication

The duplicated `"details.properties"` string literal immediately jumps into the eye. This should be in a `private static final String` constant.

On closer look,
the entire logic reading the properties file is duplicated.

#### Closing resources

The input streams used when reading the properties file are not closed.

#### Naming

Single-letter variable names like `p` are not great.
Just spell out "properties".

#### Braces

Instead of this:

> ```
> public static List<String> readFormats()
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

The common style for placing braces in Java:

```
public static List<String> readFormats() {
    // ...
}
```

#### Using Java 7

It's reasonable to require Java 7 with your utility library.
Java 6 is no longer officially supported,
those who still use are running a risk,
and should be urged to switch ASAP.

As of Java 7, you can simplify the initialization of parameterized types using the diamond `<>` operator. So instead of this:

> ```
>     Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
> ```

You can write like this:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above points together, the implementation becomes:

```
private static Properties readProperties() {
    InputStream in = PropertiesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("details.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
}

public static Map<String, String> readDetails() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Properties properties = readProperties();
    map.put("name", properties.getProperty("name"));
    map.put("version", properties.getProperty("version"));
    map.put("link", properties.getProperty("link"));
    return map;
}

public static List<String> readFormats() {
    Properties properties = readProperties();
    return Arrays.asList(properties.getProperty("formats").split(","));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, your code is well written but just my two cents.

Appending @Malachi answers as you don't need the nesting. May be he forgot to tell about:

```
if (click.getClickCount() == 2) {
            if (playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                selectedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            }
        }
```

This can also be grouped to one:

```
if (click.getClickCount() == 2 && playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                selectedMedia.setValue((Path) playList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
```

Other than that, if you are using Java 7 or 8, you should be using try with resources instead of try-catch as that is less error prone.

And instead of returning null, you should be returning an empty collection . As far as I know, returning null is not a very good approach.